# How to GetType of List<String> in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I get the type of `"List<String>"` in C# using `Type.GetType()`?

I have already tried:

```
 Type.GetType("List<String>");
 Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List.String"); // Or [String]
```

Note that I can't use `typeof` since the value I am getting the type of is a string.

Comment: Check out the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t

Comment: note that to get angle brackets to show up in text paragraphs, you must use back-quotes to format as code (as I have just edited in).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't get it from `"List<String>"`, but you can get it from `Type.GetType`:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]");
```

You're lucky in this case - both `List<T>` and `string` are in mscorlib, so we didn't have to specify the assemblies.

The `1 part specifies the *arity* of the type: that it has one type parameter. The bit in square brackets specifies the type arguments.

Where are you getting just `List<String>` from? Can you change your requirements? It's going to be easier than parsing the string, working out where the type parameters are, finding types in different namespaces and assemblies, etc. If you're working in a limited context (e.g. you only need to support a known set of types) it may be easiest to hard-code some of the details.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain what you didn't like?

Comment: Giorgi gave your same answer 4 minutes before you.

Comment: @onof: No, he didn't. He gave an answer just showing `typeof`, which he then edited when the OP explained that he needed to get the type just from the string. I was writing my answer while Giorgi was editing his. You can't see the edit because it was in the first 5 minutes, but it was obviously there, or the OP's comment wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

<del>You can use [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28VS.71%29.aspx) operator.</del>

```
typeof(List<String>)
```

See this question: [C# How can I get Type from a string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721870/c-how-can-i-get-type-from-a-string-representation)

Comment: typeif doesn't take a string as an argument. i have String s = "List<String>"

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Type type = typeof(List<String>);
```

Comment: This will not work unless you want to get type of System.Web.UI.MobileControls.List. Did you mean typeof(List<>)?

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(List<string>)
```