# Get generic type from string value representation in different dlls

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

I have 3 types all from diferent dlls y can't find how to store in a string the generic type and how to create the instance:

```
Type type1 = GetType1();
Type type2 = GetType2();
string strClassGenericType = "Namespace.ClassName<,>, DllName";

Type template = // How to get the generic template type?

Type genericType = template.MakeGenericType(new[] { type1, type2 });
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Im not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722012/1486443) fits to my requeriment.

Comment: you trying to get the type of string?

Comment: No, i need create the type represented in a string value.

Comment: For multiple type argument how is the syntax?

Comment: You always going to need to reference the namespace the class is in... I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **vcsjones** and **abatishchev** has a correct answer, but you miss about the dlls.

Thanks to **vcsjones** i used this:

```
string strGenericType = "Namespace.ClassName`2, DllName";
Type template = Type.GetType(strGenericType);

Type genericType = template.MakeGenericType(new[] { type1, type2 });
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Thanks to **abatishchev** this is shorter:

```
string strGenericType = "Namespace.ClassName`2[[Namespace1.Type1, Type1DllName],[Namespace2.Type2, Type2DllName]], DllName";
Type genericType = Type.GetType(strGenericType);

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the particular case where you want the type of object that does not have it's type parameters known, you can use a backtick with the number of type parameters. Here is an example with `Tuple`:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof (Tuple<,>).FullName); //For information only, outputs "System.Tuple`2"
var typeName = "System.Tuple`2";
var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
var generic = type.MakeGenericType(typeof (string), typeof (int));
Console.WriteLine(generic.FullName); //Outputs the type with the type parameters.
```

Comment: or `Console.WriteLine(typeof(Tuple<,>).AssemblyQualifiedName)` for more information and better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The correct string representation of a generic type is like this:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String],[System.Object]]"
```

Where `'2` means the number of generic type parameters.

For the fully qualified type name see [the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K26dlp).

---

If you're looking for a generic type having no generic type parameters specified (so called open generic) then it's this:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

Comment: I think he is asking how to take a type name that does not have the type parameters specified at all, like `Dictionary\`2`, then at runtime specify the type parameters with `MakeGenericType`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is more useful for my requirement, but vcsjones answer is little more didactic.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are trying to create a type from a string value.

Try:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("System.String");
```

eg to create a textbox type from a string:

```
Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, System.Windows.Forms, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I need a generic type.