# Convert .NET typename with generics to C# representation

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working on code generation and during this task I need to create the C# representation of the typename that may contain type parameters.

E.g. I need to get **"Dictionary<int, string>"** from **"Dictionary`2[[int], [string]]**".

In the generic case this should be a lot more complex than just string replace.

**Update to answer comments in questions**

- I'm generating source code,
- my input is either a `Type.Fullname` as string or a `Type` object (as these can be easily converted to each other).
- While not typical, my code should be prepared for **nested** type parameters.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721870/how-can-i-get-generic-type-from-string-representation) question is similar, but it refers to the opposite direction, and had no answers that could help here and don't just replace strings.

Comment: what did you try so far? It seems to be Typename`nrOfParameters[[par1],[par2]....]

Comment: Are you just generating text source code, or are you actually using the type builder system to build types?

Comment: I am sure this question has been asked before but I cannot easily find the link. Is your input a Type object or a string in the format you indicated? If it is a string then your first task is to write a lexer and parser for that language. Have you done so?

Comment: @DStanley: How does your proposed algorithm work on a dictionary mapping integers onto lists of strings?

Comment: @EricLippert That's why I deleted it.  Immediately thought of several cases where it failed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public string ToCSharpType(Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsGeneric)
        return type.FullName;

    var result = new StringBuilder();
    string name = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName;
    result.Append(name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf('`'));
    result.Append('<');
    var args = type.GetGenericArguments();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
         result.Append(ToCSharpType(args[i]);
         if (i < args.Length - 1)
             result.Append(", ");
    }
    result.Append('>');
}
```

Comment: This is the opposite direction.
However, @Servy and LukeH have pointed to an identical question that had been already answered and I can use that. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I see now. I have edited the answer.