# Web api set Generic Class dynamically according the url

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

In the below code how to set generic 'T' as a class dynamically?

Currently am redirecting all the API request to a single web api called "dummy" by routing.

So url's like

```
"api/person" then take person as class 
"api/students" then take students as class
```

So here how to pass person or students or any other dynamic  class in GenericDataController T.

```
     //web api controller 
      public class dummyController :GenericDataController<T> 
     {
        //
     }
```

GenericData web api

```
    public class GenericDataController<T> :ApiController where T : class
    {

    private IGenericDataService _dataService;
    public GenericDataController(IGenericDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
    }

    // GET: api/GenericData
    public IEnumerable<T> Get()
    {

        return _dataService.Get<T>();
    }
   }
```

In my model i have all class models

```
  public class Person{
   //
   }
  public class Student{
   //
   }
```

Comment: Normally such question should be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721870/how-can-i-get-generic-type-from-string-representation, but it sounds like you want to change routing somehow rather than just create generic type... Some clarification of exact problem may help.

Comment: Hey  edited my question, its not about string to class converstion

Comment: What you are looking for could be possible - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+webapi+generics+controller gives http://stackoverflow.com/a/20629883/477420 which may point you to direction to implement what you are looking for... (There probably exact duplicate too - you may want to search for it).