# Error in generic repository method for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a generic method to use in my base class for my repositories and I'm having an issue. Here's the method...

```
        public virtual T First(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, List<string> properties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = null;
        if (where != null)
        {
            query = _context.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("[{0}]", typeof(T).Name.ToString())).Where(where);
        }
        else
        {
            query = _context.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("[{0}]", typeof(T).Name.ToString()));
        }

        foreach (string s in properties)
        {
            query = query.Include(s);
        }

        T _result = (T)query.First();

        return _result;
    }
```

When I run the code it gives me this error:

> 'Company' could not be resolved in
>   the current scope or context. Make
>   sure that all referenced variables are
>   in scope, that required schemas are
>   loaded, and that namespaces are
>   referenced correctly. Near escaped
>   identifier, line 1, column 1.

I have an idea on why it's doing this, I just don't know how to fix it. I think it's doing it because my ObjectContext doesn't know about the object "Company" but it does know "Companies". Any ideas on how to fix this??

The error happens on this line:

> T _result = (T)query.First();

Thanks!

Comment: Usually entity set names are pluralized that's why context knows about companies. Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4. Yeah, and I'm guessing that's why it's not working...but is there a way to get it to work?

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` in case the query returns no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use

```
 query = _context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(where);
```

instead of

```
 query = _context.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("[{0}]", typeof(T).Name.ToString())).Where(where);
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks Yury! Now can you, or someone, explain why this worked?

Comment: You are welcome. Well, why this work. Introduction of `IObjectSet<T>` and `ObjectSet<T>` is one of the improvements made in efv4. In previous version it was tricky to create a generic repository since you had to know the name of entityset for entity type you were working with. Here is a good example of `Repository<T>` implementation  with except one thing: do not pass `Func<T,bool>` as a selector use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as you have already done: http://devtalk.dk/2009/06/09/Entity+Framework+40+Beta+1+POCO+ObjectSet+Repository+And+UnitOfWork.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Dan, get the entity set name with something like the following:

```
string entitySetName = context.MetadataWorkspace
                        .GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace)
                        .BaseEntitySets.Where(bes => bes.ElementType.Name == typeof(T).Name).First().Name;

string name = String.Format("{0}.{1}", context.DefaultContainerName, entitySetName);

query = context.CreateQuery<T>(name).Where(where);
```

Doing this will resolve the proper plural name for the query.

Using Yury's method would be the best option though.

**EDIT** By the way, you should return `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()` in case the query returns no entities (it will throw an `InvalidOperationException`).

Comment: Changed to FirstOrDefault(). Thanks for the help!