# How to query a DbSet with a string 'where clause'?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, repository-pattern, repository

I have the following (greatly abridged) generic repository class:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private DbSet<TEntity> _entitySet;
    private NewExternalsContext _dbContect;

    public Repository(NewExternalsContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContect = dbContext;
        _entitySet = _dbContect.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual TEntity Get(object objectId)
    {
        // TODO Figure out how to use 'id' to build an Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual TEntity FindOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return _entitySet.FirstOrDefault(where);
    }
}
```

My problem with the `public virtual TEntity Get(object objectId)` method is that because the repository is generic, I don't know that `TEntity` has any id field, or what it is called. The best I can do is check if it has an `Id` field, my most common name for id fields. Then, how do I e.g. do say `_entitySet.Where("Id = " + objectId)`? I have the `public virtual TEntity FindOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)` method, but when I just want to get an object by `id`, as is so common, I don't want to write out a whole lambda expression.

Comment: The DbSet class has a [Find method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.103).aspx) which does what you want. It finds entities based on the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will  need to create another method that returns you an entity as in this question: [How to get ObjectSet<T>'s entity key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328325/how-to-get-objectsetts-entity-key-name), you can cheat a little and get the entity by id as below:

```
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        var keyPropertyName =_objectSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers[0].ToString();          
        T entity = _objectSet.Where("it." + keyPropertyName + "=" + id).First();
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but other reading says it's as impossible to convert a DdSet<T> to an ObjectSet<T>, and I'm using DbSets. Otherwise this looks cool.